# Channel Entries outputing wrong channel

Tags: channel-entries

**EE 5.1.1**

On the home page of the site I am pulling in the latest 3 blog entries with this code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" dynamic="no" limit="3"}
<!-- Post Item -->
<div>

    <div class="post-prev-title font-alt">
        <a href="{comment_url_title_auto_path}">{title}</a>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- End Post Item -->
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

However instead of the latest 3 blog entries I get one entry titled homepage, which is the most recent entry in the system.

Have triple checked that the channel name is correct and have `dynamic="no"` parameter set so would expect this to work correctly.

Please advise.

Comment: This is often a parameter issue... is this an MSM installation? Try adding the `site` parameter (so, like `site="default"`)

Comment: Not MSM and adding `site="default_site"` or `site="default"` made no change.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was user error.

I had the entire template wrapped in another channel entries tag. Once I took the news and made it an embed all was good.